# Есть ли в CSS определение констант для цвета, размера, аналогично как сделали для шрифтов?

Tags: css

Так напрашивается эта фича...
Чтобы можно было определить цветовую палитру стиля и стандартные размеры шрифтов, отступов и тд...
К примеру:

```
@color { name: 'selected_color'; value: '#0050c0'; }
@size { name: 'main_size'; value: '15px'; }
```

И потом юзать так:

```
body { font-size: main_size; }
a:active { background-color: selected_color; }
li.selected { background-color: selected_color; }
```

есть в новых стандартах нечто подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, [в черновике](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/). Реализовано, пока-что, [нигде](http://caniuse.com/css-variables). Если очень хочется — используй CSS препроцессоры, например sass/less.

Comment: Почти успел =) А то, что они собираются добавлять переменные в чистый css это круто.

Comment: @alvoro, да. Арифметика уже есть (см. calc() http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#calc-notation), теперь алгебра будет. А потом запилят функции, разделяемые библиотеки, ООП в полный рост… и вот уже на хабре пост о веб-сервере написанном на чистом css.

Comment: @MrClon В javascript [можно][1] создавать css-классы. Допилить эту технологию и, в дальнейшем, вместо таблиц styls.css работаем с style.js. Звучит бредово (ведь есть же еще кто-то, кто вырубает js в браузере? Да и лагать может), но какое пространство для маневра - ведь мы теперь знаем все, что может динамически изменится, благодаря объектам document и window.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply

Comment: Не, это не спортивно. Надо сделать из css новый js! И переписать v8 что-бы он работал поверх css. И всё это внутри JRE, внутри KVM, внутри LXC в облаке! Вот это будет жизнь.

Ну а если серьёзно то вы со своими style.js скоро заново изобретёте Flash, Java аплеты и прочий ActiveX. Будьте проще. Это-же всего-лишь сайты.

Comment: @MrClon Да я уже воспылал праведным гневом))) Реально напрягает необходимость, в некоторых случаях, для достижения желаемого эффекта ([прижимать футер][1] к низу, к примеру), лезть в разметку и добавлять какие-то wrapper-ы. К счастью, все эти calc() и компания должны, надеюсь, полностью отделить стиль от разметки.
P.S. конечно я не пишу и не собираюсь каких-либо style.js.
[1]: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Константы есть в [less](http://lesscss.org/) и в [sass](http://sass-lang.com/). В чистом css переменных нет.